# Can't open SIM 1.5 (Sitecore instance Manager) - Profile is invalid

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-instance-manager

I'm trying to install SIM and when i click the .exe, the first settings tab does not show up.
I checked the logs and found that weird error:

```
   1 12:44:41,214 INFO  IIS.Name: Service de publication World Wide Web
   1 12:44:41,225 INFO  IIS.Status: Running
   1 12:44:41,226 INFO  IIS.MachineName: .
   1 12:44:41,226 INFO  IIS.ServiceName: W3SVC
   1 12:44:41,226 INFO  IIS.ServiceType: Win32ShareProcess
   1 12:44:41,799 WARN  The profile is invalid
System.NullReferenceException: La référence d'objet n'est pas définie à une instance d'un objet.
   à SIM.Tool.Base.Profiles.ProfileManager.get_IsValid()
   1 12:44:41,996 INFO  Wizard pipeline 'setup' starts
```

For your information, i'm using windows 10 and i tried to give full control to the inetpub folder to anyone in the privacy settings.
on the other hand, inetpub remains read only unfortunately. Can't turn off that.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the QA version of SIM and my problem disappears. Anyone knows why ?